# Error installing packages using pip in anaconda prompt (TLS/SSL error)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pip, anaconda

I installed the latest version of Anaconda Navigator from [here](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/windows/).

Once it was installed, I created a new environment named `py37` and from the anaconda navigator prompt I when I tried doing `pip install pandas`, it throws the following error:

```
(py37) C:\Users\kashy>pip install pandas
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pandas/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pandas/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pandas/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pandas (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pandas
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

[image]

**P:S.: It happens with all the packages I am trying to install**

I know there are many questions related to this, but none of them have helped me

Comment: If you use PyCharm, maybe you could add the package manually in it.

Comment: I use VSCode and Spyder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+WARNING%3A+pip+is+configured+with+locations+that+require+TLS%2FSSL%2C+however+the+ssl+module+in+Python+is+not+available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SSL module is unavailable.
Try installing OpenSSL.

[Download OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html)